# How to add a helm chart to local repository

Tags: kubernetes-helm, helm3, appdynamics

while deploying appdynamics by the helm and via gitlab-ci, I am getting the below issue:

```
$ helm repo add appdynamics-charts https://ciscodevnet.github.io/appdynamics-charts # collapsed multi-line command
++ helm repo add appdynamics-charts https://ciscodevnet.github.io/appdynamics-charts
Error: Looks like "https://ciscodevnet.github.io/appdynamics-charts" is not a valid chart repository or cannot be reached: Get https://ciscodevnet.github.io/appdynamics-charts/index.yaml: Forbidden
```

Would you mind help me how to resolve this issue?

Please take note that we have local helm repository but I am not sure how I can add the appdynamics-chart to my local helm repo.(our local helm repo is on JFrog)

would you mind helping me, please?
So far I find that we can create a package for a chart by the below commands from [Here](https://helm.sh/docs/topics/chart_repository/#store-charts-in-your-chart-repository)

```
$ helm create mychart
$ helm package mychart
$ mv mychart-0.1.0.tgz docs
$ helm repo index docs --url https://technosophos.github.com/tscharts
$ git add -i
$ git commit -av
$ git push origin master
```

but when I try to download [appdynamics-charts](https://github.com/CiscoDevNet/appdynamics-charts) I am getting the following error

```
/projects/appdynamics-charts$ helm package cluster-agent
Error: found in Chart.yaml, but missing in charts/ directory: metrics-server
```

I am not sure if am I in the correct direction. please help me to understand and resolve my issue.I am new in Helm.

Comment: seems like you need to authenticate.

Comment: @TheFool: authenticate to my local helm repo?

Comment: I am refering to your first code snippet, it says `Get https://ciscodevnet.github.io/appdynamics-charts/index.yaml: Forbidden`, although its strange because I can view it in the browser https://ciscodevnet.github.io/appdynamics-charts/index.yaml

Comment: @TheFool I think our gitlab server doesnt expose to outside, that's why I need to have them on Jfrog internal server

Comment: well, your second error tells yous that your chart is incomplete. Not sure where you got metrics server from in your Chart.yaml but you can try `helm dep build` or `helm dep update`, if you have already an index file.

Comment: @TheFool: if you go to https://github.com/CiscoDevNet/appdynamics-charts , in the root folder we have index.yaml, but  there is no chart folder. When I try *helm dep build*
I am getting this error "Error: Chart.yaml file is missing"

Comment: If you dont have a Chart.yaml yaml then its not a chart and you cannot do helm package. Its probably a helm repo, you need to put the chart for the metrics-server in its charts directory.

Comment: @TheFool Yes, I think it is helm repo. I didn't understand what do you mean by "put the chart for the metrics-server in its charts directory." I can see chart.yaml file in various folders like appdynamics-charts,cluster-agent, machine-agent.   Also please take note that I got the above error inside the cluster-agent folder that index.yaml was not available but I had chart.yaml and template folder.

Comment: In a repo you have a index.yaml and a charts/ directory. Everything listed in the index must exist as packaged chart in the charts/ directory. So either the metrics-server is missing there, or somewhere else where its referenced in a Charts.yaml. Perhaps you can share more details about the exact steps you take and show some folder structures and so on. Its hard to tell from the info you have provided.

Comment: @TheFool: thanks for the shared info, may I know after packaging what is the next step to upload it to jfrog?